# Differences between _redirect('*/*/') and _redirect('*/*')

Tags: zend-framework, magento

I am a newbie to Magento and Zend frameworks. Here are two examples in Mage_Customer_AccountController:

line 127

```
public function loginPostAction(){
  if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
         $this->_redirect('*/*/');
         return;
     }
```

and line 230

```
public function createAction()
    {
        if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*');
            return;
        }
```

What difference will these two _redirect() result in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines are equal, because Magento internally modifies url path to canonical view with "/" at the end.

The reason for writing once '*/*/' and other time '*/*' is just lack of style guidelines describing such cases for Magento developers. You can use any form you like.

Comment: Could you please tell what does '*/*/' do in the $this->_redirect('*/*/');